# Changed file access to read only but I can still write to the file. Why?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, readonly

I am running a small embedded system built using buildroot. I have come across this strange behaviour when trying to set up my file permissions on the target device. To illustrate what confuses me I tried the following simpler example

```
# cd /mydir
# touch tmp.txt
# echo "rubbish" > tmp.txt
# cat tmp.txt
rubbish

# chmod 0444 .
# chmod 0444 tmp.txt
# echo "new-rubbish" > tmp.txt
# cat tmp.txt
new-rubbish
```

I am really confused by this. How can I have set the file and directory to be read only and yet I am still able to modify the contents of this file? I have an executable within the same directory and when I try and execute it I get this

```
# chmod 0444 my_binary
# ./my_binary
-sh: ./my_binary: Permission denied
```

which behaves as I would expect it to. Clearly I have some fundamental misunderstanding of how the file access model works on Linux. Can anyone explain why I am able to write to the file that I have set to be read only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you seem to be doing this as `root` that explains you have rights to write in the directory. `root` can also append to the file even if it permissions are `-r--r--r--`.

The

```
echo "new-rubbish" > tmp.txt
```

does truncate the file (as JoelDavis pointed out), so it does not remove it and write it again (when using `bash`).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I realise now that `chmod` is not sufficient for my requirements and I need to use `chattr +i` on my files. Thanks again

Comment: @Anthon Minor point that doesn't affect the validity of your answer and I hate to be contrarian but [bash at least appears to open the file with O_TRUNC](https://dpaste.de/WYy3O/). I linked a demonstration of the idea, basically neither the inode number or the inode's crtime changes, and further greps on the strace output (not shown) don't show any `unlink` operation. It's probably more likely that the OP is noticing root's implicit possession of `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` on almost all GNU/Linux implementations.

Comment: @JoelDavis Thanks for pointing that out. I thought I remembered that things were that way as I looked at this in more detail a long time ago. But that was not with bash (I cannot remember if it was bourne or csh), on a PDP-11. So it could as easily be that my memory of things are wrong.